# Jit Tree JS & Assets Precompilation Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Am using jit tree in my rails 4 application. 
http://philogb.github.io/jit/.
While using it in local I am not getting any error. But When I deploy my app into heroku I get the following error on assets precompilation.

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(C-1))}z.computePositionStep(A,y);if(C&&x>=C)    {B.onComplete();return}}B.onStep(Math.round(x/: Unmatched ')'
   (in /tmp/build_tposeydajlt8/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
```

Comment: You don't get any error compiling assets locally?

Comment: No. It works fine if I run rake assets:precomile. But when I do RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile in local am getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting that particular line in your code. Normally, it throws this error when you have a post/pre-increment before dividing. For example, if you have,

```
i++/(C-1)
```

make it

```
(i++)/(C-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help, it may not: I was also getting asset pre-compilation errors compiling Jit, so I updated the uglifier gem with `bundle update uglifier`, and it started working.  However, the uglification itself has also been causing problems, so I might just not uglify it since the JS will normally be downloaded compressed and that should provide sufficient file size reduction.

If that doesn't work, another thing you could do is, instead of downloading the full Jit package, just download the bits of Jit you need by using the Custom build option found here: http://philogb.github.io/jit/builder.html ; perhaps the error is caused by a file you don't need.

Thanks